# Where to place the Google fonts code in <head> for maximum efficiency?

Tags: html, css, performance, embed, google-font-api

Where in your `<head>` do you place the Google fonts code for maximum efficiency / minimal page load time? Before/after your other stylesheets and scripts? Are there any considerations other than performance to take into account?

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: As long as they are in the head, it doesn't matter where they are, though you can order them to load before other scripts in your `<head>` tag.

Comment: You can place this at the beginning of your "style.css" file. As long as it is in the head it's fine!

Comment: Thanks, but the question is whether there are performance or other implications.

Answer (score 1):

You can place it at the bottom of `<body></body>` for better performance, the fonts might appear broken while the page is loading, but the page will show up faster.